# How to pull images from Firebase Storage in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I was able to successfully set up an app that uploads pictures to Firebase Storage, but now I'm having trouble showing those images on the app.

How do I pull the latest images into a FlatList or similar scrollable component? I've looked through StackOverflow for previous answers, but have had no luck. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

When you upload your file you receive a `snapshot` in the callback.

There you can find `snapshot.downloadURL`.

You can actually use those links as `src` attributes of `img` tags.

This is easier than explicitly downloading and showing the files.

EDIT: Since it might not be clear how to go about using firebase storage in practice I'd like to elaborate a bit on how I once used it.

Firebase storage as we all know does not allow for querying data so there is no efficient way to store files with relations. That is why you should always use the realtime db to store the relations.

My flow was something like this:

1. Upload file to storage
2. Store link to file in db
3. When querying for files just query the db, fetch all the links and use in the app.